# Registering DLLs and OCX

Tags: registering

I'm building an installer for a legacy program, it's a per-machine install.  The program requires a number of DLLs and OCX's to be installed and registered, partly because some of them are also used by another program which may be installed later (the 2nd program is not installed, just downloaded if wanted).  Some of them are 'standard' Microsoft libraries such as "RichTX32".

1. Is it 'better' to install these in the application folder and register them there or in SYSWOW64?
   Clearly in SysWoW they would only be installed if not already there but in the application folder they could be registered regardless of being registered already in SysWoW, but I don't know if this affects anything.  The program is installed under Program Files (x86). Some of them are likely already registered in SySWoW.
2. What difference does it make? (does it affect anything where the library is installed?)
   for example, would it affect the 2nd app in any way where it is registered from?

Many thanks